# New-SPSite in SP2013 creating sites with 2010 user interface

Tags: 2013, powershell

I am creating a Site Collection with this powershell command `$createdSite = New-SPSite -Url $SiteUrl -Name "Site Name" -Template "CMSPUBLISHING#0" -Language 1033 -OwnerAlias "spadmin"`

It used to work some couple of hours ago with 2013 experience version but suddenly it has stopped working and sites are being created with 2010 experience version. No matter if I delete the Site Collection, Web Application, restart server, recreate the Web Application with different port and DataBase Name that always the 2010 version appears and in this way.

[image]
I have also tried to specify CompatibilityVersion -15 but no luck.

Does anyone have experienced a similar issue?

Some hours ago, it worked and now it only works if I select a different publishing template like BLANKINTERNET#0

Comment: for me something corrupted on hive folders, can you run the Config wizard on server, without disconnecting the server to the farm and keep everything as is and after that try again...Config wizard will re registered all dependencies etc.

Comment: No luck. I will reinstall the virtual machine.

Comment: After reinstalling the virtual machine the problem remainss I don't know why with CMSPUBLISHING#0 the look and feel is 2010's and BLANKINTERNET#0 is 2013's. Yesterday, the look and feel of CMSPUBLISHING was 2013 UI.

Comment: how you rebuild the VM, did you re install the SharePoint from scratch? what about the databases, new or using the old? also did you try to create the site collection from central admin?

Comment: The VM is a VHD that I have as a back up (I did it some days ago so it should work now). I deleted the VHD, remove the dual boot and attached the old backup. The problem persists. The thing is that if I create it using BLANKINTERNET#0 or from Central Administration (choosing Publishing Portal in Publishing tab) it works like a charm. Any other idea?

Comment: when you run the new-spsite command, then check the ULS logs for any clue.

Comment: try this code: Get-SPWebTemplate | Where{ $_.Title -eq "Publishing Site" } | ForEach-Object{ New-SPSite http://<site name</sites/test -OwnerAlias DOMAIN\jdow -Template $_ }.........replace the url with the your desired url and id)

Comment: what does this code suppose to do? Create 4 Site Collections? Get-SPWebTemplate | Where{ $_.Title -eq "Publishing Site" }  returns 4 results

Comment: there are 4 templates for publishing sites in sharepoint 2010, i think it create for all templates one site collection....we will fix this...but question is now your site is working or still same issue

Comment: Still remains the same :( Using powershell code and selecting CMSPUBLISHING#0 doesn't work (shows 2010 UI)

Comment: How you created your Web app

Comment: With the User Interface in the Central Adminstration

Comment: I am having same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: No I didn't. I used BLANKINTERNET#0 and activated Feature "BaseSite" for search layouts

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and in my case I had to use the CMSPUBLISHING#0 template because I was moving a subsite to a site collection.

My solution was change the masterpage. Although seattle masterpage was chosen, I changed it to the oslo masterpage and worked fine, the 2013 layout experience came back. After I changed once more to seattle masterpage, and It worked perfectly. I hope this will be a solution for your case too.

By the way, if you can't access the configurations page, just add /_layouts/15/settings.aspx to the end of your site collection URL and you will be able to change the masterpage.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a parameter to specify the version:

-CompatibilityLevel 15

Without it, you may find it using the version 14 template by default because both 14 and 15 use the same template names.